# Setting default App

Tags: android, settings, default

My app have feature to send a mail. If user use this he will be prompted to open google-mail-app or another mail-app. But this selection haven't checkbox to set the current user option to default. 
Is it possible to extend the selection with a default-checkbox?

I know this checkbox from another application such navigation.

thx

Comment: What are you asking? How to make a check box? How to make settings? What selection are you talking about? This is a very poorly stated question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hardcode this into an application, however the user can do the following:

> Tap the Menu button on your phone and
>   select the Android Settings option.
>   Scroll down to the Applications
>   section and tap it. On the next
>   screen, tap Manage Applications and
>   then the All tab on the subsequent
>   screen. Scroll down the list of apps
>   until you see the old browser listed
>   and tap that entry. On the next screen
>   look for the "Launch by default"
>   section and hit the Clear defaults
>   button.

Source: http://lifehacker.com/5637923/change-the-default-application-for-any-android-phone-task

Comment: that is not answer to my question: i want to make it possible, that user can set a default application. Otherwise the user must everytime make the same selection.

Comment: No, if they can check the "launch by default" checkbox, they only need to do this once.